# Must declare the scalar variable "@??????"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using the following SQL statement :

```
      Dim strSql5 As String = "SELECT  * FROM dbo.ontledings " & _
                                " where plaasblok =  @plaasblokparsversoeke " & _
                                " and analisedatum  =  @laastedatum"


    cnn.Open()
    Dim aksie2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSql5, cnn)
    aksie2.Parameters.Add("@plaasblokparsversoeke", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plaasblokparsversoeke
    aksie2.Parameters.Add("@laastedatum", SqlDbType.Date).Value = laastedatum
    aksie2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()
```

I want to fill a datatable like so :

```
    Dim dtb5 As New DataTable
    dtb5.Clear()

    Using cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=GIDEON-E-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=SkeduleringDatabasis;Integrated Security=True")
        cnn.Open()

        Using dad5 As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql5, cnn)

            dad5.Fill(dtb5)
        End Using
        cnn.Close()
    End Using
```

I get the following error message :  Must declare the scalar variable "@plaasblokparsversoeke"

I cannot figure out where and how to declare the scalar variables.

The error occurs at the line : dad5.Fill(dtb5)

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the parameters like

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear() 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plaasblokparsversoeke", plaasblokparsversoeke.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@laastedatum", laastedatum.Text)
```

As  correctly commented below, you need to use the [Add method](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) to add the paramters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@plaasblokparsversoeke", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = plaasblokparsversoekeVariable;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@laastedatum", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = laastedatumVariable;
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thanks Rahul, My apologies. I have updated my question in which I did add the parameters to the sql command.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, avoid hard-coding a parameterised query in this way, for avoidance of SQL injection.

To answer your specific question: you are trying to use parameters in the query without having defined them in the SQLCommand.

Have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the full documentation.

Answer (score 1):

With this query

```
Dim strSql5 As String = "SELECT  * FROM dbo.ontledings " & _
                            " where plaasblok =  @plaasblokparsversoeke " & _
                            " and analisedatum  =  @laastedatum"
```

You are definining 2 SQL variables called @plaasblokparsversoeke and @laastedatum that you have to pass as parameters to your command, like this

```
command.Parameters.Add("@plaasblokparsversoeke", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@plaasblokparsversoeke "].Value = yourValue;
```

MSDN article on SQL command parameters [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just out of interest, is there a reason to add the parameter and then set it's value in separate line rather than using AddWithValue?  Or have you just done it this way to make it as clear as possible for Rahul?

Comment: `AddWithValue` has several [issues](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and should not be used anymore.